Combobox in SwiftUI
I'm trying to build a combobox in SwiftUIfor a macOS app and I've hit a wall. I have looked at other questions on here, but didn't really find any answers. The main issue I want the dropdown list to appear on top of the views below, and also on top and the parent view, similar to what the ComboBox in AppKit does. In the code below, you'll see that the dropdown doesn't even show up, due to the lack of space probably. I tried playing with z-indexes and overlays with no results.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ComboBox: View {
    let label: String

    @Binding var text: String
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var items: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TextField(label, text: $text)
                .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Button {
                        print("Clicked chyron")

                        withAnimation {
                            isExpanded.toggle()
                        }

                    } label: {
                        if isExpanded {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                        }
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
                .onChange(of: text) { _, newValue in
                    if newValue.isEmpty {
                        isExpanded = false
                    } else {
                        isExpanded = true
                    }
                }

            if isExpanded {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    @Previewable @State var text = ""
    let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
    Form {
        ComboBox(label: "Label", text: $text, items: items)
        HStack {
            Spacer()

            Button("Cancel") {
                print("Cancel")
            }

            Button("Submit") {
                print("Submit")
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }.padding()
}


Instead of overlay use sheet or fullscreen cover. You can set the background to clear

As suggested in a comment, you could try using a sheet or fullScreenCover. However, with macOS, you don't have much control over shadow effects or positioning when using a sheet and you would need to enable Mac Catalyst to use a full screen cover. I also found that Color.clear didn't work as the presentation background for a sheet (running on macOS 15.1.1).
As an alternative approach, you could consider separating the menu from the combo field and showing the menu as the top layer in a ZStack. Positioning can be done using .matchedGeometryEffect. This is essentially the same technique as used in the answer to iOS SwiftUI Need to Display Popover Without "Arrow" for showing a custom popover (it was my answer).
Some notes:

The boolean flag needs to be passed as a binding to ComboBox too.

Apply .fixedSize() to the ScrollView in ComboMenu, to restrict its size to the minimum necessary.

A catch-all tap gesture can be attached to the ZStack, to clear the popup if showing.

I found that it was difficult to get a popup-animation to work smoothly, a simple opacity transition may be safer.


struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var isComboExpanded = false
    @Namespace private var ns

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Form {
                ComboBox(
                    label: "Label",
                    ns: ns,
                    text: $text,
                    isExpanded: $isComboExpanded
                )
                HStack {
                    Spacer()

                    Button("Cancel") {
                        text = ""
                        print("Cancel")
                    }

                    Button("Submit") {
                        print("Submit")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            isComboExpanded = false
        }
        .overlay {
            if isComboExpanded {
                ComboMenu(label: "Label", ns: ns, items: items, text: $text)
            }
        }
        .animation(.spring, value: isComboExpanded)
    }
}

struct ComboBox: View {
    let label: String
    let ns: Namespace.ID

    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isExpanded: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField(label, text: $text)
            .padding(.trailing, 40)
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                Button {
                    print("Clicked chevron")
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                        .rotation3DEffect(
                            .degrees(isExpanded ? 180 : 0),
                            axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0),
                            perspective: 0.1
                        )
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: label,
                    in: ns,
                    anchor: .bottomTrailing,
                    isSource: true
                )
            }
            .onChange(of: text) { _, newValue in
                isExpanded = newValue.isEmpty
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
}

struct ComboMenu: View {
    let label: String
    let ns: Namespace.ID
    let items: [String]
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                        .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            text = item
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .fill(.background)
                .shadow(radius: 6)
        }
        .padding(.top, 6)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(
            id: label,
            in: ns,
            properties: .position,
            anchor: .topTrailing,
            isSource: false
        )
    }
}



Thank you so much for this. This is the best version I've come across so far. It suffers from the one issue that has been driving me up the walls while trying to resolve it. You need to make sure that the container can fit the dropdown, yet somehow, the ComboBox in AppKit is allowed to bend the rules of time and space and have the dropdown go beyond that.

@wombat Yes, you need to make sure that the container with the list is large enough to display it. In the solution here, the container is the ZStack and this fills the screen, so size shouldn't be a problem. You could also set a maxHeight on the ComboMenu, if necessary. However, position can still be a problem. If the combo would be near the bottom of the screen then it might be better to switch the anchors used in .matchedGeometryEffect and show the list above the button. Ps. If the answer helped, you are welcome to give it an upvote and/or accept it ;)
